# using c extension library with gevent

Tags: python, celery, gevent, eventlet

I use celery for doing snmp requests with easysnmp library which have a C interface.
The problem is lots of time is being wasted on I/O. I know that I should use eventlet or gevent in this kind of situations, but I don't know how to handle patching a third party library when it uses C extensions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem(s) are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to make easysnmp asynchronous. I have tried nothing specific.

Answer (score 1):

Eventlet and gevent can't monkey-patch C code.

You can offload blocking calls to OS threads with `eventlet.tpool.execute(library.io_func)`